# Using @click in select options - Vue.js 2

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I'd like to use @click in select options.

So far I have:

```
<button @click="sortBy('name')">sort by name</button>
<button @click="sortBy('price')">sort by price</button>
```

and it works, however when I insert it into option tag, it stopped working.

```
<select name="sortBy" id="sortBy">
  <option value="sort">sort By</option>
  <option @click="sortBy('name')">name</option>
  <option @click="sortBy('price')">price</option>
</select>
```

My function:

```
sortBy(sortKey) {
    this.items.sort((a, b) =>
    (typeof a[sortKey] === 'string' || typeof b[sortKey] === 'string') ? 
    a[sortKey].localeCompare(b[sortKey]) : a[sortKey] - b[sortKey]);
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can't bind event to `<option>`, and you need to use the `change` event of the `<select>`, once you click a option, the change event callback of `select` will be invoked:

```
<select name="sortBy" id="sortBy" @change="sortBy(sortType)" v-model="sortType">
   <option v-for="item in sortOptions" :value="item.value">{{item.text}}</option>
</select>

new Vue({
    el: '...',
    data: {
       sortType: 'sort',
       sortOptions: [
          { text: 'sort by', value: 'sort' },
          { text: 'name', value: 'name' },
          { text: 'price', value: 'price' }
       ]
    }
})
```

Once you change a option the value of `sortTyoe` will be changed to it, and the @change will call the callback `sortBy(sortType)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
One more question: is it possible to use different functions on each select option?

Comment: You can't use different functions directly, because the browser only support bind the DOM event to `select`, no `option`.