# Vue onclick sort child component in parent component

Tags: sorting, vue.js, onclick, vue-component, vuex

I'm using Vue cli and I have an array of users that I display as a profile card in template that I would like to **sort by name**.
I'm using Vuex to store data.

In the child component I have in my template:

```
<div class="outside"  v-for="(item, index) in arrays" :key="item.id" v-bind:id="item.name">
    <div class="stay">  <p class="n"> {{ item.name }}</p> </div>
```

and I'm getting the Vuex data:

```
computed: {
    arrays () {
      return this.$store.state.arrays
    },
}
```

and my array contains:

```
 arrays: [
      { name: 'Peter'},
      { name: 'Beth'},
      { name: 'Daniel'},
    ]
```

I used a function in the child component:

```
computed:{
   sortedArray: function() {
    function compare(a, b) {
      if (a.name < b.name)
        return -1;
      if (a.name > b.name)
        return 1;
      return 0;
    }

    return this.arrays.sort(compare);
  }
  },
```

and changed the template to:

```
<div class="outside"  v-for="(item, index) in sortedArrays" :key="item.id" v-bind:id="item.name">
```

**But I'd like a way to do this onclick (in the parent), instead of always displaying it in order.**

In my parent component I have:

```
<div class="begin">
<div class="b">Sort By:
                
 <select name="sort" class="sort" >
  <option value="name" @click="sortArrays()">Name</option>
 </select>
 </div>

<childComponent></childComponent>

</div>
```

I would like a sortArrays function I can use in the parent to display the user profile card in alphabetical order when I click on sort by name.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send the array from parent to child in props

## Using Props

> **Parent**

*.html*

```
<div class="begin">
  <div class="b">Sort By:
            
     <select name="sort" class="sort" >
        <option value="name" @click="sortArray()">Name</option>
     </select>
  </div>

  <childComponent :arrays=arrays></childComponent>

</div>
```

*.Vue*

```
new Vue({
  data() {
    return {
      arrays: this.$store.state.arrays
    }
  },
  methods: {
    sortArray: function() {
       this.array.sort((a, b) => return a.name < b.name ? -1 : 1)
    }
  }
})
```

> **Child**

*.Vue*

```
new Vue({
   props: ['arrays']
})
```

## Using Sort flag

Child component will accept a sort prop from parent. When Sort is clicked on parent it will be true and sent to child. On Prop Change, the child will sort and display the sorted array.

> **Child**

*.Vue*

```
new Vue({
  props: ['isSorted],
  watch: {
    isSorted: function(oldval, newVal){
      if(newVal) {
        // Do the sorting
      }
    }
  }
})
```

> **Parent**

*.Vue*

```
 new Vue({ data(){ return { isSorted: false }}, methods: { sortArrays: { this.isSorted = true; } }})
```

*.html*

```
  <child-component :isSorted=isSorted></child-component>
```

## Update

The `change` event can be binded to select.

```
<select name="sort" class="sort" @change="sortArray" v-model="filter">
    <option value="name">Name</option>
 </select>
```

In Vue

```
props: { filter: ''},
methods: { sortArray: function() { if(this.filter === 'name') // Do the sorting }}
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried doing it with props and the data is passing down but for some reason the @click isn't working. I tried doing a console.log but doesn't seem to be displaying

Comment: Have you defined the event like `@click="sortArray"`. No `sortArray()`.

Comment: I just changed it to that but still doesn't seem to display anything

Comment: Can you post your code in codesandbox so that i can understand the real problem?

Comment: Sure https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-curran-u0kr2?file=/package.json but it seems that I can't bind an event to option https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46260052/using-click-in-select-options-vue-js-2

Comment: You have to achieve it by binding `@change="sortArrays"` to `select` tag

Comment: Is there a way to display name as default text for the options menu? Because now it shows blank box by sort by and only once I click on it does it allow me to select options and shows the word name.

Comment: use `selected` in the options tag for default selection

Answer (score 1):

Add a showSorted in your data with a bool value:

```
data(){
   return {
    showSorted: false
   }
 }
```

then edit your computed to use showSorted:

```
computed:{
   sortedArray: function() {
    function compare(a, b) {
      if (a.name < b.name)
        return -1;
      if (a.name > b.name)
        return 1;
      return 0;
    }
    if(this.showSorted){
        return this.arrays.sort(compare);
     }
     return this.arrays;
  }
  },
```

and then onClick you just have to set `this.showSorted` to true;

Comment: Thanks! So I should add the bool value and modify computed in the child component? and add this.showSorted in parent?

Comment: Yes, I would use showSorted in the parent and pass down its value to the child.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Move the array, sortedArray computer properties to the parent component
And pass the array you want to be displayed to the child component as prop

handle all the logic in the parent component, here is a code snippet below that shows the basic operation. Hope you can make changes as you need.

```js
var ChildComponent = {
  template: "<div>{{ sortedArray }}</div>",
  props: {
    sortedArray: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => [],
    }
  }
}

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: { ChildComponent },
  data: {
     sortBy: "",
     array: [
      { name: 'Peter', age: 24},
      { name: 'Beth', age: 15},
      { name: 'Daniel', age: 30},
    ]
  },
  computed: {
    displayArray() {
      // declare the compare functions
      // for name
      function cmpName(a, b) {
        if (a.name < b.name)
          return -1;
        if (a.name > b.name)
          return 1;
        return 0;
      }
      // for age
      function cmpAge(a, b) {
        if (a.age < b.age)
          return -1;
        if (a.age > b.age)
          return 1;
        return 0;
      }
      
      if (this.sortBy === "name") return this.array.sort(cmpName);
      else if (this.sortBy === "age") return this.array.sort(cmpAge);
      else return this.array;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <select v-model="sortBy">
    <option value="">Please select a value</option>
    <option value="name">name</option>
    <option value="age">age</option>
  </select>
  <child-component :sorted-array="displayArray" />
</div>
```